# mouse experiment with different doses of the same drug

Tags: r, biostatistics, test-for-trend

Assuming I am running an experiment in mice with a drug treatment at different doses I have been originally thinking that a Dunnett's Test is the right analysis to perform: compare each group against the non-treatment control. However, it was mentioned here and in Harvey Motulsky's book Intuitive Biostatistics, that the fact that I have a clear order in the expected response should further narrow and drive the analysis.

I have been looking into statistical tests with a single ordinal independent variable and found the `Cochran-Armitage test for trend` in the `DescTools` R package [see pdf here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DescTools/DescTools.pdf).

> Description:
> Perform a Cochran Armitage test for trend in binomial proportions across the levels of a single
> variable. This test is appropriate only when one variable has two levels and the other variable is
> ordinal. The two-level variable represents the response, and the other represents an explanatory
> variable with ordered levels. The null hypothesis is the hypothesis of no trend, which means that
> the binomial proportion is the same for all levels of the explanatory variable.

I have three questions:

1. For the case I describe here, is this a valid analysis (increasing drug dose is ordinal variable and 'difference in in comparison to control' is the two-level response)?
2. Since I would expect my drug to decrease tumor growth (and I have no expectation or interest in an increase) would I chose "decreasing" rather than the default "two.sided"?
3. Are there other tests that similarly account for comparisons of a single ordinal (or numerical variable) with an expected trend?